# Getting Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I upgraded my wordpress site to 3.7.1 today (www.briancragin.com). 
It looks like this update is breaking my theme's portfolio page (see site nav menu) and home page carousel.

When I view source in chrome I see `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'` in the `admin-bar.min.js?ver=3.7.1:1` file. I assume there is some jquery issue going on here. Some .js file calling for an older version of jquery?

The theme's author is not being responsive. And I know nothing about jquery, rolling back jquery on my site, the theme's code or .php. But I do know how to open files in komodo and make changes. :)

Any help would be great.

Comment: .on() was introduced in version 1.7. what is the version you're using? If you're using an older version change that to .bind()

Comment: @Krishna, you're right, he's using jquery 1.6.2; but the site is functional, maybe he's trying to add new events and that's when it crashes.

Comment: @SamCcp - seems like it.

Comment: Should I change up to v1.7 or change the .on() to .bind()?

Comment: I went ahead and changed the .on() to .bind() in that admin-bar file. What problems I saw in chrome with the carousel and portfolio appear to be fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error on one of my sites too. 
Open the header.php or footer.php on your theme and looking for the line that  look like

```
<script src="http://.../jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" language="javascript"></script>
```

Change 1.6.1 to 1.7.0 - it must to work.

Try to understand what is plugin added this line? **Check up work of the plugin.**

Answer (score -1):

I'm browsing your site ( Firefox 25 on WinXp ) and there are no errors, even on IE 8 it displays and interacts correctly both the "Recent Works" section with the sliding panels and the main navigation on top of the site... Maybe you need to clear your cache and stuff?